# Shell script - input redirection when prompted by the shell script multiple times

Tags: linux, shell, unix

We have a shell script that expects multiple user inputs to be entered when prompted. e.g
At first it may ask for the operation to be performed. When that answer is given, it may ask for username then password etc. We want to automate this task by providing the inputs using file redirection i.e.
script < input.
The input file will have all the answers for different questions that the script may ask. However it is not working and the shell script is reading only the first line of the input file. What do I need to change or use to make this work?

Comment: Could you post the relevant part of the script and the first lines of the input file?

Comment: The script in question calls internal scripts they ask for the user input. I don't have visibility to those inner scripts. But it will be prompted like - "Enter the operation to perform". When user enters this operation, it will again prompt the user - "Enter the user name". I have already tried standard file redirection, but it is not working.

Comment: We can't figure out how to change something we can't see. Show the script.

Comment: The inner scripts are probably issuing a fflush(stdin) before reading, this would cause the problem that is being seen. The expect recommendation is a good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for commenting and answering. I tried except and that did not work. So I am going to mention what worked for us. Here was our workflow - 1. At the linux prompt, type the command, it was connect() in our case. 2. Once that command is given, the script would ask for parameters for the command like port number, server etc. we had to provide that manually 3. Then we again are presented with a shell prompt with another input. In our case, we were able to provide the first command connect() at the prompt using file redirection, but the parameter passing was an issue. The solution we found was provide the parameters inside the parentheses of connect only i.e. our input file for redirection would contain - connect(). This worked for us.

Answer (score 2):

What you can use is the program `expect`. You create a script for it that tells it when to give what input to some command it executes. This way you can automate exactly the kind of thing you're struggling with.

More info on Google and here:

- http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3065
- man page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Answer (score 0):

You say 'it only reads the first line of input.'

So you have to kill the script?

Is there any output? (error messages especially)?

Are you redirecting STDERR  to /dev/null or else where? If so, remove that.

Here is the hightest probability helper ... Modify the top-level script and add `set -vx` at the 2nd line. Then you'll be able to see what was processed, where it has stopped and possibly formulate theories about why it is not processing data.

Any chance that the input file was created in a Windows environment and the cr\lf pair is messing up the expected input?

I hope this helps.